# Is it possible to create a dataflow using a MongoDb dataset in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I am trying to retrieve a JSON file using a MongoDB dataset so that I can create a data flow but the MongoDB option is greyed out.

[image]

However, this works when I create a pipeline.

I can't seem to find any explanation as to why I cannot create a data flow using a MongoDB dataset.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can refer to the [Supported source types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-source#supported-sources). MongoDB is not supported as a source in dataflow.

Comment: @user3396351 Hello, if Joseph Xu's answer helps you, you can accept it as an answer. So that people with related issues can benefit from this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So refer to the [Supported source types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-source#supported-sources), we can see MongoDB is not supported as a source in dataflow now.